# MySqli Insert Error on Multiple Insert

Tags: php, mysql

So, I am using this bit of code to extract data from an XML file. When I attempt to do the insert, I get an error message. If I use the same output and to the INSERT in MySQL Workbench, it works fine. So I am assuming it's something in the way PHP is interpreting the data. Been banging my head against the wall, so any help is appreciated. Below is the code:

```
<?php

 $completeurl = "gps.kml";
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($completeurl);

 $placemarks = $xml->Document->Folder->Placemark;
 mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","V1ct0ry4439253","gps");
//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

$query = '';
$run='';
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($placemarks); $i++) {
$coordinates = $placemarks[$i]->name;
 $cor_d  =  explode(' ', $placemarks[$i]->Point->coordinates);
 $qtmp=array();
 foreach($cor_d as $value){
      $tmp = explode(',',$value);
      $ttmp=$tmp[1];
      $tmp[1]=$tmp[0];
      $tmp[0]=$ttmp; 
      $qtmp= '' . $tmp[0] . '' .$tmp[1].'';
 }

$cor_d = $qtmp;
$query .='(\''.$coordinates.'\', \''.$cor_d.'\')';
$run .="INSERT INTO gps_history (name, coordinates) VALUES ".$query."";

//break;
 }
 echo $run;
 mysqli_query($con,$run);

mysqli_close($con);
 ?>
```

Comment: So are you saying that if you dump the output from `echo $run` into MySQL Workbench it runs without error?

Comment: Yes sir that's correct. At least the last query, which is incremental as it counts through each record.

Comment: You're doing an echo $run inside your loop and also outside your loop.  It looks like you've been doing a lot of different attempts to fix this (there's evidence of multiple different debug code).  I see $cor_d and $qtmp are not actually being used (it seems)...  

Maybe it would help if you could copy/paste the echo output here (as a comment or edit your response) and we could help troubleshoot it more.

Comment: Here's a sample of the output (I ran out of space to put more in)
INSERT INTO gps_history (name, coordinates) VALUES ('SC Assessor P9', '38.51275-89.98531'),('SC Assessor P1', '38.51979-89.99249'),('SC Assessor P2', '38.51278-89.98524'),('SC Assessor P3', '38.51274-89.98526')

Answer (score 0):

Many database connections by default will not allow multiple queries strung together in a single statement separated by commas (as a safeguard against one type of SQL injection).  It's possible that this is what you're experiencing.

Try moving `mysqli_query($con,$run);` *inside* your loop and ensuring that it is only running one query at a time.

Comment: If this is not the solution, could you specify exactly what error you're getting/seeing?  And include the actual verbatim echo output from the multiple `echo $run;` statements?

Comment: Here is the error message I'm receiving:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';INSERT INTO gps_history (name, coordinates) VALUES ('SC Assessor P9', '38.51275' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gps.php:36 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gps.php(36): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO gps...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gps.php on line 36

Comment: I tried putting the query inside the loop, and still get an error

Comment: Remove the last comma in `$query .='(\''.$coordinates.'\', \'\'),';` (after the right parenthesis).

Comment: I'd also suggest removing the final semicolon inside your query line `$run .="INSERT INTO gps_history (name, coordinates) VALUES ".$query." ;";` (NOT the one to end the PHP statement... the one inside the quotes).  This is because of the SQL injection protection... the database might be rejecting it because it looks like you're trying to run multiple queries at once.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code up top. Still the same results though.

Comment: Two more things.  You are not resetting $run and $query inside your loop each time.  Therefore, you also need to change `$run .=` to `$run =` (remove the dot, which appends to the existing string).  And the same for $query... change `$query .=` to `$query =`.  I think this will make it start working for you.

Comment: Ok, so that allowed the INSERT to complete successfully but only inserted one row. I'm at a complete loss here. EDIT: Moved the query BACK to the loop, and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.  And welcome to StackOverflow.com.  I'm still relatively new to this as well.  If you found my answer helpful, you can help me earn points by upvoting my response or marking it as the correct solution.  It took some back and forth since your code has a lot of intricacies but it seems that the problem was mainly related to (a) SQL Injection preventing multiple queries, and (b) trailing comma and semicolon.